# can we use prepared statement without setter methods?

Tags: jdbc

We see that prepared statements in java are used for pre-compiled SQL statements. Can we use a prepared statement for an INSERT query without the setter methods and provide the data directly in the statement declaration?

Comment: -1 You could have tried this yourself and found out it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if there are no ? placeholders, in which case it reduces to a Statement, but it's a really bad idea. Read up about SQL injection.

Comment: As a matter of fact, i did read about SQL Injection after i posted this question. But anyway, thank you for your help.